# Sorting data from an oracle procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, cursor

I have a procedure that returns the similarity between any chosen record and all the other records in the DB as shown below:

```
Similarity between:
record_3 and record_1 > 0.4
record_3 and record_2 > 0.2
record_3 and record_4 > 0.5
record_3 and record_5 > 0.7
record_3 and record_6 > 0.0
...
```

I would like to know if there is a way to order this data to show the top 3 similarities as show below?

```
Similarity between:
record_3 and record_5 > 0.7
record_3 and record_4 > 0.5
record_3 and record_1 > 0.4
```

I have found one way to achieve this by creating a table before the procedure is called, printing the result, then dropping the table, but this seems like quite a bad solution.

Is there anyway I could store the result in cursor and order it within the cursor?

Any help you be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your procedure's code (or at least a simplified example that demonstrates the problem)?  I would expect that you'd just add an `ORDER BY` to the query used to open the cursor but perhaps there is more to your problem than that.  Is your similarity score coming from `utl_match` or have you implemented your own function to compute this?

Comment: I will post the code later today. Apologies for not posting with the original question. I have implemented my own similarity function that I call within a loop that inserts the data into a table, then orders that to get the top 3. However, this seems wasteful.